# Sophos home blocks explorer.exe from encrypting several files (ransomware?)

Tags: encryption, antivirus, ransomware

Here's what happened:
I was transferring a quite large number of small files (.CSV, .PNG above all) from an old USB stick that never gave me any problem from one (allegedly safe) laptop (win10, win defender) to another one (also allegedly safe, win11 with Sophos home).

I get a warning from Sophocle that says that it blocked explorer.exe from executing malicious attack, but not malicious Software has been found in the files. Checking the history in the dashboard, the software refers to blocking a ransomware attack, as explorer.exe was try to encrypt a number of files. The files involved were created by myself with the first laptop through python hence they can't contain malware.
After the warning I tried to still move those files, without success. Also, if I tried to change name or move other files from other folders, explorer was asking me for admin rights to do so. Even after giving admin rights, I could not move the files as it would say that I require the rights from "Everyone". Since I thought Sophos somehow killed explorer.exe, I rebooted the laptop. No issues in moving or renaming files, until I tried to move those same files mentioned above. Same warning as before, same issue. I repeated the process of rebooting and trying to move those files a few times ro understand what was going on, a few times getting warming about a potential ransomware from explorer.exe and some other time from surrogate com 10 (but looking in the dashboard history it was referring to dllhost.exe). A couple of times I had a message that I needed the admin rights from LAPTOPNAME to do the action, but the issue was gone after rebooting. Except for the laptop seeming a bit slower (maybe it's my imagination) I don't see anything strange. No processes taking up much cpu or ram. A full Sophos scan revealed no threats. I did not try open some files on the laptop to see if they are actually encrypted but it seems to me that their extensions have not been changed (as it would instead happen from ransomware attack).

What do you think about the story? Have I been attacked by ransomware or did Sophos allucinate? By trying to move some files after the issue, and giving admin rights in the attempt to do so, could I have triggered something bad? Why would the action of copying files from the USB stick trigger an encryption attempt (and warning from Sophos)?

Comment: Did you modify your explorer.exe, shell or anything like it?

Comment: Nothing at all. The day before a standard windows update was installed

Comment: It may be detecting that the file is changing enough that it MIGHT be in the process of being encrypted. Meta-data may be changing because of a change to the formatting of the USB drive vs. the format of the hard drive?  (fat-32, ntfs, etc..)  Or just that the created/modified dates will change when moving the file(s).  If the file is small enough maybe it triggers sophos' protection?  Your admin prompts may be related to Sophos flagging the files.

Comment: That seems a plausible explanation. Especially because those admit prompts go away after rebooting (except only for one time, bit after rebooting again it was fine).If it was a true ransomware and eventually got triggered, I think I should see strange extensions.im the files, which I don't. Some suggestions on how to exclude further that there is a malware/ransomware somewhere? Maybe Malwarebytes?

Comment: Sophos should have a good scan... just run that.   Installing two anti-virus programs can cause some problems.